# Float right div over left div for media query

Tags: html, css

So i'm developing a website with Skeleton. This website is supposed to have the following lay-out at Desktop:

[image: Desktop Layout]

When I resize the browser, or open it on a mobile however, the div's are getting places this way:
[image: Mobile Layout]

I would like to have the left div go under the right div. So the text comes first and then the picture. (only on mobile).

The following code makes the section:

```
  <section class="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="one-third column">
                <img class="u-max-full-width" src="images/person.png" alt="Person" height="300" width="200">
            </div>
            <div class="two-thirds column">
                <h4>About</h4>
                <p>Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem.</p>
                <p>Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna.
                    Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

How do I configure this the right way with CSS?

Comment: can we see the css as well? 
Since I have a solution with flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @frnt for getting me on the right path. As it turns out, the solution was pretty simple. I added this to my CSS and it's working right out of the box:

```
@media (max-width: 750px) {
#container {
display: flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have not added `css` for your `html` codes, so here are `two example` through which you could achieve as above i.e. change `div position at small screen`.

**Solution - 1** - By setting `position relative to child divs` and at `mobile` i.e. using media query change there position at `small screen resolution`.

```css
#container{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
#container > .box{
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  background:#f2c;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
#container > .box1{
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  background:#ff2;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
#container > .box{
    width:100%;
    top:100px;
  }
#container > .box1{
    width:100%;
    top:-100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box1">2</div>
</div>
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78t9v75f/) and resize output size to see changes.

**Solution - 2** Using `css3 flex`,

```css
#container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-around;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
}
#container > .box{
  flex:1;
  background:#ff2;
}
#container > .box1{
  flex:1;
  background:#f22;
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
  #container{
  flex-direction:column-reverse;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box1">2</div>
</div>
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uo8y8a5s/1/)

**Again you have not added css, so this is examples which could work.**

Comment: @Jesse Hope this help.

Comment: I love flex so + 1 for flex solution. 
However you can write less code by just having `#container` selector on mediaquery. 

modify  `flex-direction: column` with `flex-direction: column-reverse`

this way you wont need the other 2 blocks ^_^

Comment: Yes @Nicholas that's right :-), nice you suggested that thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Works partly. The divs are being stacked the right way, but because  I have another section underneath, the image goes straight through. (Using the CSS3 flex method by the way)

Comment: @Jesse Set height for .container, as in 1st fiddle if I set it's height from auto to the total height of two divs i.e. 300px then below section doesn't gets effected, create a section to see that. https://jsfiddle.net/78t9v75f/3/

Comment: @frnt  Can't get the first method to work. Because i'm using Skeleton class names i am  not sure where to replace .box and .box1 with. (see original question for html)

Comment: @Jesse Check this jsFiddle hope this help, it keep space between sections https://jsfiddle.net/mmmju9uj/1/

Comment: @frnt thanks again. Can't get it to work. Are you able to reacreate the jsfiddle with my example?